# Carousel-Arrows change their color, depending on the picture displayed?

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel, arrows

How can I make the Carousel-Arrows changing their colors, depending on the picture displayed beneath them?

For example, if I have a bright picture, arrows are black; when I have a dark Picture, arrows are white.

Here is an example of the effect: http://www.herschelsupply.com/

Thank You!

Comment: I hope it was what you were looking for :)

Comment: Glad it suits your needs, happy to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to look at this interesting jQuery plugin called **BackgroundCheck**:

http://www.kennethcachia.com/background-check/

This plugin automatically switch to a darker or a lighter version of an element depending on the brightness of images behind it.

**Download** the minimized version from Github: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kennethcachia/Background-Check/master/background-check.min.js

**How to use:**

If an element overlaps any of the images, either .background--dark or .background--light is added to it. BackgroundCheck does not change an element's style — you must do so using CSS.

```
p.background--light {
  color: black;
}
```

For more detailed information, check the **documentation here**: 
https://github.com/kennethcachia/Background-Check

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @Quentin: Now edited with more info. Not sure though if it's enough now. Please let me know.